# Cambiar formato de horario en FullCalendar

Tags: java, html, css, json, fullcalendar

Hola quisiera saber si fullCalendar tiene la opción de cambiar su formato de horas que aparece en el lado derecho.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que pasara de 1, 2, 3 a 1am, 2am, 3am y así sucesivamente.
Eh provado con esto: `timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',`

Pero creo que es mas que nada para el horario que sale dentro pero lo que me interesa es los costados. Espero su ayuda, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación te dice como cambiar [timeFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timeFormat) en la v3, pero tambien estan otras verciones. Aqui el ejemplo que pone:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title:  'My Event',
      start:  '2010-01-01T14:30:00',
      allDay: false
    }
    // other events here...
  ],
  timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
});
```

Comment: Que raro amigo, no me hace ningún cambio.

Comment: Que versión utilizas? Busca tu versión y prueba, debería funcionarte